# How to loop through object inside object in react

Tags: reactjs

Can someone explain to me what is wrong I am doing? I want to loop through the object and display properties of the User object.

[image]

What I have done so far

```
class CustomLayout extends Component {
    render(){
   const { auth } = this.props;

return(
  <div>
                 <div>{
                    Object.keys(this.props.auth).map((key) => {
                        return this.props.auth[key].map(msg => <p>{msg}</p>)
                    })
                }</div> 

</div>
);

}
} 

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
    auth: state.auth

});


export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { logout }
)(CustomLayout);
```

Comment: Please also mention the error that you are getting

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```js
{
  this.props.auth.user && Object.keys(this.props.auth.user).map((key) => {
    return (
      <p>{`${key}: ${this.props.auth.user[key]}`}</p>
    )
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You again need to get the `key's` from `user` object like,

```
<div>{
    this.props.auth && Object.keys(this.props.auth).map((key) => {
      if(Object.keys(this.props.auth[key]).length > 0){
        return Object.keys(this.props.auth[key]).map(msg => <p>{this.props.auth[key][msg].toString()}</p>)
      }else{
        return <p>{this.props.auth[key].toString()}</p>
      }
    })
}</div>
```

Or, if you only want to display `user` object and don't bother about the other properties you can do this,

```
<div>{
    this.props.auth.user && Object.keys(this.props.auth.user).map((key) => {
        return <p>{this.props.auth.user[key]}</p>
    })
}</div>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-stduqm)

Comment: Looks like the correct way to do it. Don't know why this is downvoted.

Comment: No luck. TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: @ravibagul91 I tried your solution, Its showing TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null. I have updated my question. Please check

Comment: It means that you are getting `auth` object null for intial render. Check this condition `{this.props.auth.user && Object.keys(this.props.auth.user).map( ... )}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
const myObject = {
 a: 'somestring',
 b: 42,
 c: false,
 d : {x :'weeee',t : 'test'}
};

for(var z in myObject.d){
 if(myObject.d.hasOwnProperty(z)){
  console.log(myObject.d[z]); // "weeee", then "test"
 }
}
```

Or you can do with a for-of loop as well

```
for (let value of Object.values(myObject.d)) {
  console.log(value); // "weeee", then "test"
}
```

Comment: what if I need to display only one property from d? like if I need to display the only t from d?

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of destructuring and [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), Also don't forget to add `key` when mapping over an array

```
class CustomLayout extends Component {
  render() {
    const { user } = this.props.auth;

    return (
      <div>
        {user && Object.values((val, i).map(key => <p key={i}>{val}</p>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```